# How to use fast Fourier transform for the complex values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I solved a differential equation and the solutions of that are the complex values in the time domain. I have to transform it to the frequency domain with [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). I have used FFT in MATLAB, but the answers are not correct. How can I choose my interval of frequency?

The time domain is between -10 and 60 and the number of steps is 1000.

```
function r = fur()
    clc
    clear
    format long
    a = -10;          % tmin
    b = 60;           % tmax
    m = 1000;         % Number of steps
    t = zeros(1, m);
    y = zeros(1, m);

    t(1) = a;         % Boundary condition
    y(1) = 0;         % Boundary condition
    t0 = 0.01;
    h = (b-a)/m;

    for j=1:m
        T = t(j); Y = y(j);
        k1 = h*Fun(T, Y);
        k2 = h*Fun(T + h/2, Y + k1/2);
        k3 = h*Fun(T + h/2, Y + k2/2);
        k4 = h*Fun(T + h, Y + k3);
        y(j+1) = Y + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6;
        t(j+1) = a + h*(j);
    end

    % real_y = real(y);
    % imag_y = imag(y);
    y;

    %% Fast Fourier transformation for P(W)

    NFFT = length(y);
    fs = 2*pi/h;
    X = fftshift(fft(y, NFFT));
    fVals = (0:NFFT-1)*fs/NFFT;

    figure(1)
    plot(fVals, abs(X), '-b');
    title('Fast Fourier transform');
    xlabel('Frequency (THz)')
    ylabel('p(w)');

    hold on


    %% Fast Fourier transformation for E(W)

    NFFT = length(y);

    fs = 2*pi/h;
    Z = fftshift(fft(Et(t, t0), NFFT));
    fVals = (0:NFFT-1)*fs/NFFT;

    figure (2)
    plot(fVals, abs(Z), '-r');
    title('Fast Fourier Transform');
    xlabel('Frequency (THz)')
    ylabel('E(w)');
    hold on

    %% Linear susceptibility

    f = X./Z;
    f_imag = imag(f);
    f_real = real(f);
    fVal = (0:NFFT-1)*fs/NFFT;

    figure(3)
    plot(fVal, f_real, '-r');
    title('total part of susceptibility');
    xlabel('Frequency (THz)')
    ylabel('Kappa(w)');
    hold on

    figure(4);
    plot(fVals, f_imag, '-r');
    title('imaginary part of susceptibility');
    xlabel('Frequency (THz)')
    ylabel('kappa(w)');
    hold on
```

And this is the *Fun.m* file:

```
function F = Fun(t, y)
    format long
    E_g = 1.52; % Binding energy for GaAs
    gamma = 0.1*E_g;
    t0 = 0.01; % This is a damping operator
    k = 1;
    F = -i*((((k^2)-i*gamma)*y)-Et(t, t0)); % F = -i*((-i*gamma)*y-1/2);;
```

And this is the *Et.m* file:

```
function e = Et(t, t0)
    format long
    t0 = 0.1;
    e = (1/2)*(exp(-(t/t0).^2));
end
```

Comment: What does the complex values represent in your differentiation? What does applying FFT mean to the complex values? Are you sure you do not want to take the magnitude of the complex values?

Comment: y is the complex value and is matrix with the complex values.

Comment: what should I do right now?

Comment: There are a lot of things that are unclear in your question, for example "time domain is between -10 and 60 " you have negative time? Or just negative values - but then you said your values are complex, so are these the real part of the values? I am really confused.

Comment: in the figure matlab just considers the real part but when you print the values of y that are complex. because the differential equation is complex equation so the solution would be complex. the time has negative value. yes it is just value. the value that I said is complex is y. i wanted to transform y values from time domain to frequency domain.

Comment: It is better to add after obtaining y in frequency domain I have to transform the Et fro time domain to frequency domain and at the end I want to obtain the division of two values from fourier transform as I called it  in the code 'f' value.

Comment: The FFT of a complex signal should only give the real positive frequency part, the phase (imaginary part) need to be fft shifted - I think you are after `fftshift`, see if this helps http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/8202

Comment: But I used fftshift .like the example in the page that you sent it.

Comment: Note: The OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 6 years ago"*